# Having troubles with the ecdsa library for python

Tags: python, blockchain, bitcoin, ecdsa

I wanted to test out if the elliptic curve code (to derive a public key from a private key) from the book Mastering Bitcoin by Andreas Antonopolous would work...so I copied and pasted the code in the book to my VSC editor. It prompted a few errors that made me delete the 'L's at the end of the parameters and inserted the necessary parenthesis after the print statements. Now I am still encountering errors such as "unable to import ecdsa.util"...

Below is the code I am using and attached is the snapshot of the error it shows:

```
import ecdsa
import random

from ecdsa.util import string_to_number, number_to_string

_p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
_r = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141
_b = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007
_a = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
_Gx = 0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798
_Gy = 0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8
curve_secp256k1 = ecdsa.ellipticcurve.CurveFp(_p, _a, _b)
generator_secp256k1 = ecdsa.ellipticcurve.Point(curve_secp256k1, _Gx, _Gy, _r)
oid_secp256k1 = (1, 3, 132, 0, 10)
SECP256k1 = ecdsa.curves.Curve("SECP256k1", curve_secp256k1, generator_secp256k1,
oid_secp256k1)
ec_order = _r

curve = curve_secp256k1
generator = generator_secp256k1

def random_secret():
    random_char = lambda: chr(random.randint(0, 255))
    convert_to_int = lambda array: int("".join(array).encode("hex"), 16)
    byte_array = [random_char() for i in range(32)]
    return convert_to_int(byte_array)

def get_point_pubkey(point):
    if point.y() & 1:
        key = '03' + '%064x' % point.x()
    else:
        key = '02' + '%064x' % point.x()
    return key.decode('hex')

def get_point_pubkey_uncompressed(point):
    key = '04' + \
          '%064x' % point.x() + \
          '%064x' % point.y()
    return key.decode('hex')

secret = random_secret()
print ("Secret: ", secret)

point = secret * generator
print ("EC point:", point)

print ("BTC public key:", get_point_pubkey(point).encode("hex"))

point1 = ecdsa.ellipticcurve.Point(curve, point.x(), point.y(), ec_order)
assert point1 == point
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Mastering Bitcoin's python code is based by python2
and python3 has changed string encode and decode.

this is right activated code with python3

```
import ecdsa
import os
import binascii
from ecdsa.util import string_to_number, number_to_string

_p = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFFC2F
_r = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141
_b = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007
_a = 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
_Gx = 0x79BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798
_Gy = 0x483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8
curve_secp256k1 = ecdsa.ellipticcurve.CurveFp(_p, _a, _b)
generator_secp256k1 = ecdsa.ellipticcurve.Point(curve_secp256k1, _Gx, _Gy, _r)
oid_secp256k1 = (1, 3, 132, 0, 10)
SECP256k1 = ecdsa.curves.Curve(
    "SECP256k1", curve_secp256k1, generator_secp256k1, oid_secp256k1
)
ec_order = _r

curve = curve_secp256k1
generator = generator_secp256k1


def random_secret():
    convert_to_int = lambda array: int(binascii.hexlify(array), 16)
    byte_array = os.urandom(32)
    return convert_to_int(byte_array)


def get_point_pubkey(point):
    if point.y() & 1:
        key = "03" + "%064x" % point.x()
    else:
        key = "02" + "%064x" % point.x()
    return binascii.unhexlify(key)


def get_point_pubkey_uncompressed(point):
    key = "04" + "%064x" % point.x() + "%064x" % point.y()
    return binascii.unhexlify(key)


secret = random_secret()
print("Secret: ", secret)

point = secret * generator
print("EC point: ", point)

print("BTC public key: ", binascii.hexlify(get_point_pubkey(point)))

point1 = ecdsa.ellipticcurve.Point(curve, point.x(), point.y(), ec_order)
assert point1 == point
```

and the result is this

```
Secret:  45144777120122405140812796301557992803916792041985925168483786699489296135626
EC point:  (97022596039543818601440182171533278426801313043337446429800654678890979695199,53586405348987121115764110810505844890885198959743315511392863714433787991327)
BTC public key:  b'03d680d7e3daf984534507c6ddd7d7cfa07864daf6b78d5b52bf657ecb636a9a5f'
```